# How to detect first Windows boot?

Tags: c++, windows, credential-providers

I have a Windows credential which must negotiate with a service only one time (and no more) and it is when the Windows firstly boots up.

using "cpus" parameter in "SetUsageScenario" function, we only can detect the difference between unlock and log out scenario. The point is how to detect first Windows log on?

Comment: Do you mean the first time the system is booted after installing Windows or just the first time the machine is booted after it has been turned off?

Comment: When I installed windows 10, it booted several times before it prompted me or game me the windows prompt.

Comment: I mean, every time Windows boots. but i just want to manage the credential scenario.

Comment: You can't detect first logon since it has nothing to do with providers scenarios.
This is not an authentication scenario as UNLOCK or CHANGE_PASSWORD are.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the `Windows Service` is the best way to detect `Windows` boot.

When you are registering service you can provide that your service don't support `Stop` command and mark it as `auto-start`.

There (at service start) you can be sure that the windows have just ben booted.